# Default value in URL request or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, coding-style

Please suggest your idea about coding style.

In a web form, there is one option but it's not required to select. Its values are 1, 2 and "All". Value "All" is a default value when form is loaded, 'All" means of both of 1 and 2.
Depend on selected value, a request will be sent to server for processing. Server will parse this value and return a result response. I have 2 ways in the case which user choose "All" value:

> 1. Don't include option value in request. My example URL will be **"../Process.aspx"**. Server will detect and know that user selected "All" value.
> 2. Include option value in request with specific value (ex: -1). My example URL will be **"../Process.aspx?option=-1"**. Server will detect and know
>      if value is -1, that means user have selected "All" value.

Please suggest me the best solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variation 1 seems more natural to me. It doesn't specify a filter, so naturally, *all* elements should be returned.

It is also consistent with the way RESTful APIs work: `http://server/api/files` will return all files. `http://server/api/files/test.txt` will return a specific file.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a variation of option one.

If the value of option is unknown or unspecified use the default. If the option value is -1 (or whatever value is associated with the default selection) make sure to handle this in the same manner. In the case of an unknown value I would also log the value. Ie if you are using a logger log this as debug information. This often becomes very handy when you add new values and can't figure out way the system seems to ignore these.

handling unknown values as default values ensures that a bookmark/link with deprecated options will still work to some extend giving a better user experience than an error message

Answer (score 1):

I would take approach one.

Firstly check if the option parameter is set. If not, assign it a default value in your code.
If it's assigned check the input and do your processing. This way you also need to manage your code at 1 place. (for default values)

Answer (score 0):

"All" should be given a numerical value (like 3).  The markup for the element should probably look like this:

```
<select name="fieldname">
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">All</option>
</select>
```

The server should read the POST response and use a switch control statement to decide what to do with the values.

```
switch(postvar):

case 1: // processing for 1 value goes here

case 2: // processing for 2 value goes here

case 3: // processing for "All" value goes here

endswitch;
```

Comment: The general rejection of GET values doesn't make any sense. It *might* make sense for security related info, but than, one could simply use a paket sniffer to get that info. The only reason to *not* include something in the URL but to put it in the body is to avoid that sensitive information is accidently shared by the user of your application, e.g. when he copies the URL from his browser and gives it to his buddy and the URL contains his Session ID or similar.

Comment: "as this may allow someone to gain insight into your application" - let us be realistic here. A potential hacker will inspect the POST request anyway and gain the same insight into the application. Having these non-security, user-settable parameters in `GET` is better because it allows a user to simply share the URL so that someone else can see the same set of results.

Comment: Agreed.  I removed the unfounded rejection of GET values.

Comment: I'd prefer All=0, that way you can extend later to add an option 3,4,5 etc without having to alter the value of All